# Android app emulator for Mac to run popular games

Tags: android, macos, emulator

I'm looking for Android app emulator for macOS which can support popular games.

So far I've tested [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/), but for example [King of Avalon game](http://www.bluestacks.com/apps/strategy/king-of-avalon-dragon-warfare-on-pc.html) didn't work well, because the emulator was [crashing often](https://bluestacks.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115017892763-BlueStacks-crashes-on-macOS-Sierra) and I had other [in-game graphics problems](https://bluestacks.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115009400566-King-of-Avalon-problem-with-graphics) (too dark colors), so it's basically buggy. Secondly Mac version is not officially supported and there are no plans to fix these bugs.

Are there any more reliable, stable Android app emulators for macOS which can support popular games from the market?

Comment: just check on [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com) whether it meets your requirements or not.

Comment: @GBolt I think it is, here is the [download link](https://www.genymotion.com/download/) (for Windows, Linux and Mac), also some [trial versions](https://www.genymotion.com/download-trial/), I haven't tested yet, but I will. Please post it as answer then, it's still useful info.

Answer (score 1):

Download [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/download) for a best usage of an android emulator.

Before that, you should create an account of your own in genymotion and mention the purpose of the use, you will get a required license for that purpose.

And your system should have latest version of [virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org) to work with Genymotion.